# In Tikz, how to set a node's label alignment to the left?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple node (rectangle) with a label a the top. I would like that label to appear on the top left, but I'm failing at understanding how to do so. Here's what I'm aiming for:

[image]

and here's my code:

```
\node [rectangle, label={Grid}] at (3.25, .25) {};
```

I've tried things such as setting

```
label={[align=left]Grid}
```

but they will not align the label to the left. They will put the label on the left side of the node, instead. Also,

```
label={[left=4]Grid}
```

worked in the sense that it moved the label to the left, but also somehow screwed its vertical positioning. Trying to then correct for it with

```
label={[left=4, above=1]Grid}
```

didn't work, although doing the `above=1` individually did move it upwards.

A MVE of the last situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [label={[left=4]:Grid}, draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=7cm] at (0, 0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but ideally I would like to just tell it to left align it for me.

Comment: Could you please add a MWE starting with `\documentclass`and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Matthias just updated the OP.

Comment: Where is the label exactly supposed to be? A simple drawing might help to understand this.

Comment: Sure, see the edited post.

Comment: Note that label always creates a second node placed relative to the current node.  You really save noting using label, and you lose the ability to add different options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=7cm] at (0, 0)(r) {};
\node[above right] at (r.north west){Grid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

With label only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=7cm,name=r,label={[shift=(r.north west)]above right:Grid}] at (0, 0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No. I put a picture on the OP to aid you.

Comment: Stellar, thanks! But I'm curious, is there a way to do it based on the label?

Comment: I propose another solution with label only.

Answer (score 7):

With a label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [label={north west:Grid}, draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=2cm] at (0, 3) {};
\node [label={[anchor=south west]north west:Grid}, draw=blue, rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=2cm] at (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax for the label is `position:label text` and the top left of a node is called `north west`. However, specified position is used for the bottom right of the label in this case, while it should be used for the bottom left. To do this you can specify the anchor point as a label option.

Answer (score 3):

One can do much shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (10,-7) rectangle (0,0) node[above right,black]{Grid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]